# How do you declare an object array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to declare an array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200621/how-to-declare-an-array-in-java)

Suppose I have an object car (class vehicle) and I want to create an array of N number of cars .  How do I declare that in Java?

```
vehicle[N]= car=new vehicle [];
```

Is this right?

Comment: convention in Java is that class names are Capitalized

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's the other way round:

```
Vehicle[] car = new Vehicle[N];
```

This makes more sense, as the number of elements in the array isn't part of the type of `car`, but it *is* part of the initialization of the array whose reference you're initially assigning to `car`. You can then reassign it in another statement:

```
car = new Vehicle[10]; // Creates a new array
```

(Note that I've changed the type name to match Java naming conventions.)

For further information about arrays, see [section 10 of the Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/arrays.html).

Answer (score 3):

Like this

`Vehicle[] car = new Vehicle[10];`

Answer (score 2):

```
vehicle[] car = new vehicle[N];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way:

You should declare the length of the array after "="

```
Veicle[] cars = new Veicle[N];
```