# Use a for loop to speed up defining variables Java Android

Tags: java, android, loops

I know that you can't use a for loop to create multiple variables with numerically patterned names but is there any way I can simplify the following lines of code with some kind of loop? Otherwise it's a very long file that does very little, and I don't like that! Here's a shortened version of my code.

```
public DrawGrid(Context context, int[] binary) {...
sq00c = binary[0];  
sq01c = binary[1];  
sq02c = binary[2]; ...etc}

Rect sq00 = new Rect(); Paint sq00p = new Paint();  int sq00c;  
Rect sq01 = new Rect(); Paint sq01p = new Paint();  int sq01c;  
Rect sq02 = new Rect(); Paint sq02p = new Paint();  int sq02c; ...ect

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {...
sq00.set(2*sqsize, line0, 3*sqsize, line0+sqsize);  sq00p.setColor(sq00c);  sq00p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);   canvas.drawRect(sq00, sq00p);       
sq01.set(3*sqsize, line0, 4*sqsize, line0+sqsize);  sq01p.setColor(sq01c);  sq01p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);   canvas.drawRect(sq01, sq01p);
sq02.set(4*sqsize, line0, 5*sqsize, line0+sqsize);  sq02p.setColor(sq02c);  sq02p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);   canvas.drawRect(sq02, sq02p);
...etc}
```

Each of the three parts of code above occur 64 times each. Is there any way to simplify it with a loop? Thanks

Comment: Can't you use arrays?

Comment: I had read that in a similar question here but wasn't sure how to implement it in my situation.

Comment: i think that arrays or lists may help you, if yes i can put an example

Comment: An example would really help.

Comment: It's possible you're looking for a 2d array?

Comment: For your information, please note that there is a StackExchange site specialized in reviewing working code called [codereview.SE]! Do not repost this question there as it has already been answered, but if you ever need some other review be free to post there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
private int[] myInt;
private Rect[] myRect;
private Paint[] myPaint;

public DrawGrid(Context context, int[] binary) {
    myInt = binary;
    myRect = new Rect[myInt.length];
    myPaint = new Paint[myInt.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < myInt.length; i++) {
        //Put Rect parameters here, you have to take advantage of the "i" variable 
        myRect[i] = new Rect();

        myPaint[i] = new Paint();
        myPaint[i].setColor(myInt[i]);
        myPaint[i].setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    }
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    for (int i = 0; i < myRect.length; i++) { // < not >
        canvas.drawRect(myRect[i], myPaint[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked great, although you had > instead of < in the for loop and it took me ages to realise!

Answer (score 0):

Keep an array of Rects, Paints, and ints (or, better yet, put them all in a nice, encapsulated object and keep an array of those ) and initialize them in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

For example, try this:

```
Rect[] rects=new Rect[SIZE];
```

and see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132049/how-do-you-declare-an-object-array-in-java)